# Need to change directory in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, backup, cd-command

I am trying to change a directory in a bash script in order to delete a file after it has been transferred. Here is my script and what I would like to do:

Please see line 5:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 name=$(date '+%y-%m-%d')
  3 tar -zcf /var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup$(date '+%y-%m-%d').tar.gz /opt/splunk/etc/
  4 rsync -avz /var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup* svc_splkbup@10.x.x.x:/var/log/splunk/backups/essearchhead
  5 cd /var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup*
  6 rm splunkbackup*
```

Comment: ..and the problem is? Though I can't see how `/var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup*` would expand to a single directory, since two lines above you created a file whose name matches the pattern.

Comment: Why not just use `rsync --remove-source-files`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti would my command be:

rsync -avz --remove-source-files /var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup* svc_splkbup@10.x.x.x:/var/log/splunk/backups/essearchhead

Comment: It would indeed.

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` has a built-in method to do what you seem to be trying to do manually:

From `man rsync`:

> **--remove-source-files**
>
> This  tells  `rsync`  to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `/var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup*` will likely expand to a list of *files* rather than to the name of a directory that you can change into.

My guess is that line five should read

```
cd /var/tmp/backups
```

or, that line five *and* six would be replaced by the single line

```
rm /var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup*
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change directories.

5 `rm /var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup*`

6 ``

although recursive force might be in order

5 `rm -rf /var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup*`

6 ``

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to deal with just one archive file at a time, you could just save the filename to a variable:

```
file=/var/tmp/backups/splunkbackup$(date '+%y-%m-%d').tar.gz
tar -zcf "$file" /opt/splunk/etc/
rsync -avz "$file" svc_splkbup@10.x.x.x:/...
rm "$file"
```

Though you may want to only delete the file if the transfer succeeds, so this instead:

```
rsync -avz "$file" svc_splkbup@10.x.x.x:/... &&
  rm "$file"
```